# Maximum of two line breaks

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex

I have the regular expression:

```
Comment = Comment.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

After this is run, I only want there to be a maximum of two breaks. For example, 3 or more `<br />` will compound into `<br /><br />`.  This will stop people leaving huge gaps.

Can anyone show me how this is done?

### Test case

```
Hello


This is my
Test





Peanut

Case
```

This should turn to:

```
Hello<br /><br />This is my<br />Test<br /><br />Peanut<br /><br />Case
```

Also it should work if there are any number of `&nbsp;` between `<br />` tags

Comment: Are you looking for `\n` or `<br />`?

Comment: Either!  I've replaced with `<br />` so matching those might make most sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go through and replace instances of 3 or more newlines in a row with `"<br /><br />"`. Then make a second pass and replace all remaining new lines with `"<br />"`

The following is a quick console application to demonstrate.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string content = "Hello\r\n\r\n\r\nThis is my\r\nTest\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nPeanut\r\n\r\nCase\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";

            Console.WriteLine("Here is the unmodified string:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(content);

            content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(\r\n){2,}", "<br /><br />");
            content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\r\n", "<br />");

            Console.WriteLine("Here is the modified string:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(content);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is the best, but it could even be simplified. `Comment.Replace("\\n{2,}", "<br/><br/>"); Comment.Replace("\\n", "<br/>");` I was trying do it with one function call, but I am unfortunately just not that good with RegEx anymore.

Comment: @pickypg - agreed your changes make this easier to read.  I have updated my code above - Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: This seems to replace a lot more than expected!

Comment: Ah I should have phrased my question better, it should be, 2 continuous `<br />` not total of 2 in the string

Comment: @Tom - Hi Tom I updated my solution with a quick console app so you can see how this solution works.

Comment: @Dough, works brilliantly, but the only issue is it can be bypassed by inserting spaces between line returns, I'll try and see if I can work out how to filter those out

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
  Regex regex = new Regex( "((<br\ />(\s*)){3,})" );
  string result = regex.Replace( commentText, "" );
```

Comment: I've made this mistake before.  You'll replace any occurrences of more than two, with none.  You'll want to replace the String.Empty with two "<br>"s.

Comment: This will only replace instance of 3 or more newlines - you still need to have another regex to get the instances of < 3 newlines.

Comment: @Mark Whoops! Absolutely correct.  @Doug Isn't that the goal? I thought he wanted to leave 1 or 2 newlines, but have 3 or more replaced down to two.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following REGEX to match two or more `<br />` when they are separated only by whitespace:

```
(<br />\s<br />\s*)(<br />\s*)*
```

I'll leave the syntax for the replacement to you.

Comment: +1 But your answer needs to be edited to get rid of the `&lt;`. Also you need to mention that the match needs to be replaced with `<br /><br />`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# regex flavor but this may work:

```
regex : /(\n\n?)\n*/

replace : $1 or \1
```